# gradle.daemon react-native: Could not find or load main class “Dorg.gradle.daemon=true”

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, react-native

When I try to build the project with the command 'react-native run-android' the following error appears:
**Error: Could not find or load main class “Dorg.gradle.daemon=true”**

```
JS server already running.  
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...
Error: Could not find or load main class “Dorg.gradle.daemon=true”
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
```

**.bash_profile** contains the following global variables:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/Android-SDK
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Hom 
export GRADLE_OPTS=“Dorg.gradle.daemon=true”
```

I have my emulator running and I have ran the command "source ~/.bash_profile".

**All I want is to enable gradle daemon and execute the project**.

Comment: Don't know if this is the reason but should be rather: `GRADLE_OPTS="-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"`, mind the dash `-`.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#N104AD also states this statement so you should be fine when using the dash

Comment: @Opal Thanks very much. I needed the "-" and remove the "export" statement. I wiil except your anwser if you write it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this is the reason but should be rather:

```
GRADLE_OPTS="-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
```

mind the dash `-`.

Comment: May I know where to edit that line? I am having the same issue, but don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @Joel, this is an env variable.